# Can I use Droid Explorer to migrate my apps and app data from one device to another?

Tags: backup, droid-explorer

Examples:

Migrate from old Firestick (small one) to a new one?
Migrate from Note 4 to Note 8?

Or is ADEBAR or something like that a better solution?

If Droid Explorer is the solution can anyone point me at the steps? Not seeing anything after some searching - tho to be fair, this app came off a post in a StackExchange post.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest to migrate that you can do without additional apps. From what I know, use Android 6 and newer with a valid Google account where all Playstore apps are recorded. I have not tried on older than Android 6 for these to work.

Enable its Google backup and auto sync options. Activate all application that have a backup/restore, such as Whatsapp.

When you login to the new device, the contacts, wireless settings and those auto backup can be restored. The respective Android apps from Google Play Store are listed as Library in My apps & games. Select and install back the required games.